# "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6"

Tags: steam

I am running XFCE through crouton on my Chromebook. I wanted to install Steam but I'm having a problem. It says Steam needs to install `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and `libc6:i386`. And each time I try to run it, it says `You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6`.

Can anyone help me out with my problem?

Answer (score 2):

`libc6.so.6` is in the package `libc6-i386`, so install that package too.

---

The `libc6.so.6` you are missing is the 32 bit version from `/lib32/libc6.so.6`.  There is another 64 bit version in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` but that's not the one you need for Steam.  After installing all the missing 32 bit libraries steam needs, you will still need the 32 bit loader, which is also in the `libc6-i386` package.  Once the 32 bit loader is present, the `ldd` script run on your Steam executable will produce output listing the required libraries, and which are missing.
The 32 bit packages may be distinguished from the 64 bit versions by adding ":i386" to the package name when installing, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

The `libc6:i386` and the `libc6-386` packages are probably the same. Some people suggest:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt-get update
```

commands, but I've never had to do that.

Comment: I already have libc6.so.6, for some reason it still wont work

Comment: How would I install the missing 32 bit libraries that it needs? Sorry I am new to linex/ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following commands fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt-get update*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do for my Ubuntu 18.04 installation, and follow this closely.

Firstly, as others mentioned, run the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, go to this page and download libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_i386.deb:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/libnvidia-gl-390/download

Next, cd to the download directory and run the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg -i libnvidia-gl-390_390.48-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

And all should be right with the world; you are now ready to Steam!

Answer (score 0):

if you enabled linux apps beta and installed steam from the website xterm will also install open then sudo apt upadte and sudo apt upgrade allowed me to install the steam updates to run steam!

Answer (score 0):

You may have something in your PATH that breaks Steam. E.g. Linuxbrew. Removing it from PATH and launching steam from terminal helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh --reset` will fix it.
It will reinstall dependencies upon next launch.